# Invalid Syntax when plotting a plot in python

Tags: python, numpy

```
nonlin = flux_2/fit_2  

polyfit_function = np.polyfit(flux_1[:,:,:], nonlin, 3, full=True) 
fit = np.polyval(polyfit_function, np.arange(np.min(flux_1),        np.arange(np.max(flux_1)))

plt.plot(flux_1[i,j,:], nonlin,'.')
plt.plot(np.arange(np.min(flux_1),np.max(flux_1)), polyfit_function)
plt.show()
```

The syntax error that showed was:

```
plt.plot(flux_1[i,j,:], nonlin,'.')
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm unsure as to why this error occurred because I used this previously in the code. Matplotlib and numpy are imported already.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 5):

You have five open parens on the previous line, but only four closing parens.